# Overlapping Circles in Leaflet - How to change layer drawing order?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using leaflet to create a proportional symbol map.  Without boring you with the code, I'm wondering if there is a way to draw smaller symbols on top of bigger ones.  There doesn't seem to be any set order to my current symbols, so bigger circles sometimes obscure the smaller ones.

Just to clarify: I'm trying to re-arrange smaller circles on top of big ones and they are in the same layer.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your "symbols" / circles are individual vector shapes (typically `L.circle`), then you can use [`bringToFront()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-bringtofront) and [`bringToBack()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-bringtoback) methods to change their relative order.

Comment: Hmm, well, this is one single layer of circle points, could bringToFront() still apply in re-ordering their order?  I always thought bringToFront was to manipulate multiple layers?

Comment: In Leaflet, a layer is an individual feature. Without seeing your code, it is difficult to say what exactly applies to your situation.